# Yum dependencies and metadata for java-headless

Tags: linux, java, yum, tomcat9, rocky-linux

I'm trying to install Java 8 and Tomcat 9 on a RockyLinux 9 server.

Installing tomcat (from EPEL) requires `java-headless >= 1:1.8.0` which is resolved to `java-11-openjdk-headless`. So Java 11 gets installed as a dependency... even though I have already installed `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless` and it should, 'logically', provide `java-headless >= 1:1.8.0`.

```
$ yum deplist tomcat
Last metadata expiration check: 1:37:02 ago on Tue 28 Mar 2023 04:13:15 PM CEST.
package: tomcat-1:9.0.65-2.el9.noarch
[...]
  dependency: java-headless >= 1:1.8.0
   provider: java-11-openjdk-headless-1:11.0.18.0.10-2.el9_1.x86_64
[...]
```

I guess `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless` lacks the `Provides: java-headless` metadata. It is not in the `yum whatprovides java-headless` output. But I'm not sure how I can check the full metadata of `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless`.

Is there a way to:

- force yum to ignore the `java-headless` dependency ?
- mark `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless` as providing this dependency ?

or any other option that would allow me to avoid :

1. installing Java 11 for no use
2. forcing Java version through `alternatives` or through tomcat configuration ?

EDIT: Java 8 and 11 both get installed without conflict. I would just like to avoid installing Java 11. Tomcat 9 is compatible with Java 8 and runs fine after selecting Java 8 from `update-alternatives`.

Comment: What do you have installed that needs `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless` ?

Comment: I have installed it. The app I need to run on Tomcat requires this version of Java exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a version dependency conflict while installing Tomcat 9 on your RockyLinux 9 server.

The best way to fix that would be to install Java 8 separately, but since you have it already you can install `Java 8 Development Kit` (JDK) separately then set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the Java 8 installation directory.

So first download the `Java 8 JDK` from the Oracle website or through the OpenJDK repository, then set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the `/etc/profile` file or in the Tomcat startup script (`/usr/share/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh)` it should be `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java8`

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear enough, I have edited it. There is no conflict between versions, they get installed side-by-side correctly. I know there are multiple ways of telling tomcat which Java to use, I would just like to avoid installing Java 11 if possible.